# Django openid authentication issue when I changed the url domain of my site but kept the same database

Tags: django, authentication, openid, authorization, postgresql-9.1

I should first note that I am a newbie in python/django applications but I am trying hard to learn :)

I am working/experimenting on a django project that supports login through openid providers. So I was able to login through my google account with no problems.

Recently, I decided to **change the url of my site** but at the same time I kept the current database because I dont want to lose my data,users etc. After that point, I am not able to login to the application. This is the following scenario that happens all the time:

- Try to login to my site
- Site doesn't remember me and I am redirected to google server
- I fill my credentials in google server
- I am redirected to my site that complains that the user already exists

So, I don't know how to manage with this problem. Is there any workaround or a hack that I can do to my database that will solve this problem? When I browse to my database I find several tables that may be related:

django_authopenid_association, django_authopenid_nonce, django_authopenid_userassociation,django_authopenid_userpasswordqueu

One of the tables in my database (django_authopenid_association) contains the following data. Do you believe that If I reset anything there is going to help?
[image]

If you have any good advices/tips are more than welcome.

Thanx

Comment: Seems like Google provides different OpenID URLs for different clients. Try to use other OpenID profile, which has static URL (based on your username, for example). If it works, then you'll only need to remove google's openid data.

Comment: Thanx for the tip! I just found a solution to my problem, before your post, but I can try it and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution/temp hack that worked for me. Of course, this doesn't imply that my solution is the optimal nor that I recommend this to anyone else.

What I did is to create a second account to my application using the same gmail account but having different user name. Then, I edit the new entry in the **django_authopenid_association** table, copy paste the **openid_url** value and use it for my old  user (database entry 1 in the screenshot of my question).

After that, since I was able to login with my old user, I delete from the database the new user and everything seems to work smoothly until now.